# Can anyone speed up this code?

Tags: php

I've got this bit of php here that is very sluggish. Not millisecond sluggish, but causes the page to load in 8 seconds sluggish.

What it is doing is pulling Actor and Director information from a 3rd party movie database with a json string, for each of the 20 movies on the page.

I've done some testing and worked out that my code here must be fine. It's the connecting to the database 20 times that is the problem.

So other than reducing the amount of movies on the page from 20, is there anything else I could do?

```
echo '<h3>Starring</h3>
      <p>';
$num_actors = 0;
$films_result = $tmdb->getMovie($film->id);
$films = json_decode($films_result);
foreach ($films as $film) {
foreach ($film->cast as $cast) {
  if ($cast->job == 'Actor') {
    echo '<a href="person.php?id=' . $cast->id . '">' . $cast->name . '</a> ';
    $num_actors++;
    if ($num_actors == 5)
    break;
}
}
echo '</p>
      <h3>Director</h3>
      <p>';
foreach ($film->cast as $cast) {
  if ($cast->job == 'Director') {
    echo '<a href="person.php?id=' . $cast->id . '">' . $cast->name . '</a> ';
  }
}
echo '</p>';
```

I don't know if it will help, but here's the database's documentation page on the call I am making to it - http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/methods/Movie.getInfo

Comment: Does the third-party movie database allow you to send a json-encoded array of person ids?

Comment: I could try if you showed me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it safe to assume getMovie will only return results for 1 movie? if so you can rid yourself of the foreach $films loop but we'll leave that for now.

don't loop twice - if you find the director then move onto the next loop...

```
echo '<h3>Starring</h3>
      <p>';

$films_result = $tmdb->getMovie($film->id);
$films = json_decode($films_result);
foreach ($films as $film) {
    $i=0;
    foreach ($film->cast as $cast) {
        if ($cast->job == 'Director') {
            $dir = $cast;
            continue;
        }
        if ($cast->job == 'Actor') {
            echo '<a href="person.php?id=' . $cast->id . '">' . $cast->name . '</a> ';

            if ($i%5 == 5) break;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    echo '</p>
          <h3>Director</h3>
          <p>';
    echo '<a href="person.php?id=' . $dir->id . '">' . $dir->name . '</a> ';
    echo '</p>';
```

this script will only show a mximum of 5 actors - beware of that it may not be what you intended

Comment: It's worth noting that there can be more than one director listed. I assume this would not show more than one?

Comment: Tried this and for some reason it also showed all Actors, not just 5.

Comment: thats my bad $i%5 == 0 it what it should say.. and yes this will only show one director - you could have $dir as an array and add each director like $dirs[] = $cast; then you foreach $dirs as $dir

Answer (score 1):

Don't loop through the `$film->cast` objects twice (actor then director). Rather, loop once, saving the html result in a variable and then outputting that variable at the end of the loop.

Comment: How would I do that? Sorry. Should've mentioned I'm an EXTREME beginner.

Comment: @rowanc88, you can use concatenation to store as a variable (html codes) to be printed at the end of all the data parsing.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few options:

1. Make the calls to the remote database in parallel. Take a look at [curl_multi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php). It allows you to make several requests to remote pages at once.
2. Since it sounds like the slowest part is accessing the remote database, you might also want to consider using a caching mechanism on the returned database results such as [memcached](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) or [apc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) to remember the results for a given movie from a previous request.
3. If 1 and/or 2 don't work well enough for you, you may also consider downloading the movie database (if allowed) nightly or weekly to a local sqlite/MySQL database and read your results from there instead.

Comment: Having a look at the curl thingie, but no unfortunately I can't cache it. Not allowed under the T&C

Comment: Hmm... any pointers for the curl_multi? I have no idea where I could put it in. Would I put it in amongst the code I've listed above?

Comment: @rowanc88 Actually caching it appears to be allowed for reasonable periods in order to provide your service (T&C: 1.B.iii). Depending on how often this data is accessed and how often it changes I would suggest returning a cached result while fetching a fresh one in the background. Caching it for a few hours or even a day or so should be considered reasonable for a relatively static movie database.

Comment: To use curl_multi, you could first iterate through all the titles you need information on adding them to the multi request, execute the multi, then, once it's finished, loop again through all the returned results to display them.